# How is this term an expected value of a binomial distribution $B(n, (1-p))$?

Tags: probability

I have the following term of which I was told that it can be simplified to $n(1-p)$ as it is an expected value of a binomial distribution.

$$
\sum_{x=0}^{n}(n-x)\binom{n}{x} p^x(1-p)^{n-x}
$$

My problem is that I can't see it. If I think of an expected value for $1-p$ I would expect something like this:

$$
\sum_{x=0}^{n}x\binom{n}{x}(1-p)^xp^{n-x}
$$

Could anyone please show me how the first term can be an expected value of $B(n, (1-p))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand out into two sums: $\sum_{x=0}^n (n-x) (nCx) p^x (1-p)^{n-x}$
= $n \sum_{x=0}^n (nCx) p^x (1-p)^{n-x} - \sum_{x=0}^n x (nCx) p^x (1-p)^{n-x}$
The first sum looks like a sum of all probabilities, the second looks like the expected value of a Binomial $(n,p)$ distribution. Can you see what to do next?

Comment: Thank you, I was unable to see that the sum $\sum_{x=0}^n (nCx) p^x (1-p)^{n-x}$ had to equal 1, as the sum of all x over a probability distribution is 1. The other half is the standard expected value for a binomial distribution.

Answer (score 2):

If $X \sim B(n,p)$, then

- $E(X) = np = \sum_{k=0}^nk\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$

Now write

- $k = k-n + n$

So, you get

$$np = n\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}}_{=(p+(1-p))^n = 1} - \sum_{k=0}^n (n-k)\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

Hence using $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$ you get
$$\underbrace {\sum_{k=0}^n (n-k)\binom{n}{n-k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}}_{=E(Y),Y\sim B(n,1-p)} = n - np = n(1-p)$$